# Searching database with combo box and displaying multiple results

Tags: sql, database, vb.net, search

I am trying to create a program that will search for animals based on name. I currently have that part working, however I would like to add an optional search so that the user can search for specific data such as weight and the combo box would display the results of all the animals with have the matching weight, and the user can then select the one he wants and it will open up the form I have designed with the correct data displayed. Unfortunately I have a very basic understanding of programming so any help will be much appreciated.

Here is my current code. The main search feature works however the optional one does not. I was told it is due to the way I have programmed it, being that each line of sql replaces itself so it will only end up with the last answer.

```
Private Sub btnsear_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnsear.Click
    If (txtname.Text = "") Then
        MsgBox("Invalid Search")
    Else
        Try
            Dim newsql As String
            newsql = "select * from Animals where AnimalName like " & "'%" & txtname.Text & "%'"
            'MsgBox("select * from Animals where AnimalName like " & "'" & txtname.Text & "'")
            'msgbox(newsql)
            Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
            Dim da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter

            ' dim ds as NewDataTable
            Dim dt As New DataTable("Animals")
            ' uses the 2010 compatible connection string
            con.ConnectionString = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source = h:\Animals.accdb"
            con.Open()

            da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(newsql, con)
            da.Fill(dt)

            Form2.Show()

            'show name in unbound text box
            Form2.nametxt.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item(1)
            Form2.latintxt.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item(2)
            Form2.locationtxt.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item(3)
            Form2.heighttxt.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item(4)
            Form2.weighttxt.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item(5)
            Form2.diettxt.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item(6)
            Form2.statustxt.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item(7)
            Form2.lifetxt.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item(8)
            Form2.breedtxt.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item(9)
            Form2.lengthtxt.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item(10)
            Form2.txtimage.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item(11)

        Catch
            MsgBox("Item Not Found")
            'con.close()
        End Try
    End If

    If (txtopt.Text = "'") Then
        Try
            Dim sql1 As String
            Dim sql2 As String
            Dim sql3 As String
            Dim sql4 As String
            Dim sql5 As String
            Dim sql6 As String
            Dim sql7 As String
            Dim sql8 As String
            Dim sql9 As String
            Dim sql10 As String

            sql1 = "select * from Animals where AnimalName like " & "'%" & txtopt.Text & "%'"
            sql2 = "select * from Animals where LatinName like " & "'%" & txtopt.Text & "%'"
            sql3 = "select * from Animals where Location like " & "'%" & txtopt.Text & "%'"
            sql4 = "select * from Animals where AverageHeight like " & "'%" & txtopt.Text & "%'"
            sql5 = "select * from Animals where AverageWeight like " & "'%" & txtopt.Text & "%'"
            sql6 = "select * from Animals where DietaryNeeds like " & "'%" & txtopt.Text & "%'"
            sql7 = "select * from Animals where ConservationStatus like " & "'%" & txtopt.Text & "%'"
            sql8 = "select * from Animals where AverageLifeSpan like " & "'%" & txtopt.Text & "%'"
            sql9 = "select * from Animals where BreedingSeason like " & "'%" & txtopt.Text & "%'"
            sql10 = "select * from Animals where AverageLength like " & "'%" & txtopt.Text & "%'"

        Catch
        End Try
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Kindly add the proper tag of programming language used.

Comment: Done, sorry I forgot :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like...

```
Private Sub btnsear_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnsear.Click
    If txtname.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Invalid Search")
    Else
        Try
            Dim newsql As String = "SELECT * FROM Animals WHERE AnimalName LIKE " & "'%" & txtname.Text & "%'"

            If txtopt.Text <> "" Then

                newsql &= " AND (AnimalName LIKE " & "'%" & txtopt.Text & "%'" & _
                          " OR LatinName LIKE " & "'%" & txtopt.Text & "%'" & _
                          " OR Location LIKE " & "'%" & txtopt.Text & "%'" & _
                          " OR AverageHeight LIKE " & "'%" & txtopt.Text & "%'" & _
                          " OR AverageWeight LIKE " & "'%" & txtopt.Text & "%'" & _
                          " OR DietaryNeeds LIKE " & "'%" & txtopt.Text & "%'" & _
                          " OR ConservationStatus LIKE " & "'%" & txtopt.Text & "%'" &    _
                          " OR AverageLifeSpan LIKE " & "'%" & txtopt.Text & "%'" & _
                          " OR BreedingSeason LIKE " & "'%" & txtopt.Text & "%'" & _
                          " OR AverageLength LIKE " & "'%" & txtopt.Text & "%')"
            End If

            Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
            Dim da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter

            Dim dt As New DataTable("Animals")

            con.ConnectionString = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source = h:\Animals.accdb"
            con.Open()

            da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(newsql, con)
            da.Fill(dt)

            Form2.Show()

            'show name in unbound text box
            Form2.nametxt.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item(1)
            Form2.latintxt.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item(2)
            Form2.locationtxt.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item(3)
            Form2.heighttxt.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item(4)
            Form2.weighttxt.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item(5)
            Form2.diettxt.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item(6)
            Form2.statustxt.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item(7)
            Form2.lifetxt.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item(8)
            Form2.breedtxt.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item(9)
            Form2.lengthtxt.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item(10)
            Form2.txtimage.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item(11)

        Catch
            MsgBox("Item Not Found")
            'con.close()
        End Try
    End If

End Sub
```

I've not tested this, and looking in more detail, this assumes all your columns are characters columns.

If you have a mix of Ints, Dates, Chars and so on, which you most likely have, then you may need to be more specific about your search terms. where you will need to seperate your optional SQL out depending upon which optional search your user is attempting.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I have tested this code in my program by trying to search for a record. Both records had the same animal name 'horse' but had different conservation status's. Unfortunately when searching for the different record it didnt't work e.g. I searched for horse with the optional box having the data of 'alive' and it returned the record where the conservation status  was 'dead' as it was cam before the 'alive' record.

I completely appreciate your quick response on this topic :)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply... Does your form have a ComboBox for them to select which Optional Search they are performing?